# Accessing other program's memory

Tags: memory

I have been experimented around accessing memory used by other programs and I've encountered a little bit strange (to me) results.
First I have created a variable in my first program and gave it the value of 10. Then I looked at the address of it and asigned it manualy to a pointer in my second program. After that i tried to derefrence the pointer and (to my surprise) the program didn't crash. Instead it printed derefrenced pointer's value as 0
Next I created a few other programs to experiment with this. In my first program I created a pointer and asigned 'new int' to it. Then I checked the address of the int and manually asigned it to another pointer in my second program. Now when i tried to derefrence the ptr of my second program it did crash.
Could someone explain why the difference happened? And why was the derefrenced pointer 0?
Sorry for a possibly stupid question :/

Comment: Until you know what you're doing... _don't_. Raw memory access is difficult and risky even if you have the right knowledge behind it, which clearly isn't the case here. Establish a firm base of how your OS/implementation manage memory, practice and practice manipulating memory within a single process, and _maybe_ then start thinking about "experiment[ing] around accessing memory used by other programs". Just kidding - still don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the addresses that your program prints for you to see are virtual addresses. Virtual addresses are relative to the memory space of each individual program. They get converted to physical memory addresses by the operating system during runtime.

So you didn't really access the real (physical) memory address of one of your programs from another one. This is also why the pointer value was set to 0.